# MemoryError Python, in file 99999999 string

Tags: python, memory

Windows 10 pro 64bit, python installed 64bit version

> The file weighs 1,80 gb

How to fix thiss error, and print all string

```
def count():
    reg = open('link_genrator.txt', 'r')
    s = reg.readline().split()
    print(s)
```

Comment: How big is your file? It would seem you have a very large file.

Comment: The file weighs 1,80 gb

Comment: Right, well depending on how many newlines (none or 1 at the end) and how many spaces (every other byte) occur in your file, Python could require as much as ~4.5Gb or as little as 30 bytes to process `reg.readline().split()`. What is the format of your file? How long is the biggest line?

Comment: The format of the txt file, and which is the largest line, I have no idea (

Comment: Right, well with so many unknowns I'm going to have trouble helping you. Try `print(reg.read(1024))` and see what it prints out (the `1024` arg will limit read to reading at most 1Kb of data). Or better yet, use a command line program like `less` to inspect the file.

Comment: he output 1024 lines, the last line was not complete was missing 11 characters

Answer (score 0):

`reg.read().split('\n')` will give a list of all lines.

Comment: same as reg.readline().split() and your solution, didn't work!

Comment: same////////////////////

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do `s = reg.read(65536).splitlines()`? This will give you a hint on the structure of the content and you can then play with the size you read in a chunk.
Once you know a bit more, you can try to loop that line an sum up the number of lines

Comment: that is, it prints all the lines from my file, if I know how many of them there are?

Comment: how to display full file, with weight of 1.80 gb?

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the answers and trying to understand what the initial question could be I come to more complete answer than my previous one.
Looking at the question and the code in the sample function I assume now following:

- is seems he want to separate the contents of a file into words and print them
- from the function name I suppose he would like to count all these words
- the whole file is quite big and thus Python stops with a memory error

Handling such large files obviously asks for a different treatment than the usual ones. For example, I do not see any use in printing all the separated words of such a file on the console. Of course it might make sense to count these words or search for patterns in it.

To show as an example how one might treat such big files I wrote following example. It is meant as a starting point for further refinements and changes according your own requirements.

```
MAXSTR = 65536
MAXLP = 999999999 
WORDSEP = ';'

lineCnt = 0
wordCnt = 0
lpCnt = 0
fn = 'link_genrator.txt'
fin = open(fn, 'r')

try:
    while lpCnt < MAXLP:
        pos = fin.tell()
        s = fin.read(MAXSTR)
        lines = s.splitlines(True)
        if len(lines) == 0:
            break
        # count words of line
        k= 0
        for l in lines:
            lineWords = l.split(WORDSEP)# semi-colon separates each word
            k += len(lineWords)         # sum up words of each line
        wordCnt += k - 1                # last word most probably not complete: subtract one
        # count lines
        lineCnt += len(lines)-1
        # correction when line ends with \n
        if lines[len(lines)-1][-1] == '\n':
            lineCnt += 1
            wordCnt += 1
        lpCnt += 1
        print('{0} {4} - {5} act Pos: {1}, act lines: {2}, act words: {3}'.format(lpCnt, pos, lineCnt, wordCnt, lines[0][0:10], lines[len(lines)-1][-10:]))
finally:
    fin.close()
    lineCnt += 1
print('Total line count: {}'.format(lineCnt))
```

That code works for files up to 2GB (tested with 2.1GB). The two constants at the beginning let you play with the size of the read in chunks and limit the amount of text processed. During testing you can then just process a subset of the whole data which goes much faster.